# Filter Form with VBA using SQL returning 2465 can't find the '|1'

Tags: sql, vba, forms, filter, ms-access-2010

I have a form that I want to have filtered by default to the day's work orders. But occasionally, I may want to see all open work orders or even all work orders. I have put 3 buttons on the forms two for the special filters and one to return to the default.

```
Private Sub cmdTodaysWO_Click()

    Dim strFilter As String

    strFilter = "Today's Work Orders"

    Call FilterForm(strFilter)

End Sub
```

I set up a sub procedure to make things easier. The code for each button is similar so I will only show one. I have tried to use direct SQL queries from VBA with ADO, using SQL text with QueryDefs, and finally saving queries in Access and calling them in QueryDefs and ADO but they all return the error.

```
Private Sub FilterForm(FilterText As String)

    On Error GoTo FilterForm_Err

    'Database Query Connection
    Dim conn As QueryDef
    Dim myData As Recordset

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

    'open saved query
    Set conn = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(FilterText)

    'bind parameters
    'conn![PackageParam] = "*" & Me.txtkeywordspackage & "*"

    Set myData = conn.OpenRecordset()

    Form.[Form_Work Order Details].Recordset = myData

    Form.Requery


FilterForm_Err_Resume:

    If (adStateOpen) Then
    
        myData.Close

    End If

    Set conn = Nothing

    Exit Sub

FilterForm_Err:

    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly

    GoTo FilterForm_Err_Resume

End Sub
```

I have been able to open and run the queries by themselves but it is only when I try to bind them to the form in the line below that I get the error.

```
Form.[Form_Work Order Details].Recordset = myData
```

It happens no matter which method I use. I have looked for spaces, grammatical errors such as parentheses, but I could not find any. I am trying to filter the main form, not a subform.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that `"Today's Work Orders"`, including the single quote, is a valid name?

Comment: I did notice one thing while I was debugging the code. When the button was first pressed and entered the function, even before the connection to the QueryDefs was set, the Form.Recordset property was returning the error.

I do not think this has to do with the coding but something to do with access or the design. It works when VBA is not doing anything but it is only when I am trying to filter the form that I am running into this problem.